# VB.NET check range of cells in excel whether data length is less then 7, add "wwww" to the left until it becomes 7 characters

Tags: vb.net, excel, substring, vba

i was wondering if is there any vb.net function that loop through excel file and check for the data length under a specific column?

i've got a column where the data shouldn't be less than 7 characters

any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

There are countless examples of getting excel data, so this answer is just for the padding.

You can use `String.PadLeft` using the overload that supplies length and the character to pad with.

```
Dim yourString = "test"
yourString = yourString.PadLeft(7,"w")
```